# Why doesn't a generic NSDictionary warn me about incorrectly-typed key inserts/assignments?

Tags: objective-c, generics

Why don't the following `NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary` calls produce an error or warning?

I expect an error here because the rhs `NSDictionary` literal doesn't match the generic types of the `NSDictionary` lhs local variable.

```
NSDictionary<NSString *, NSNumber *> *foo = @{ @(42) : @"foo" };
```

I expect an error here because the key type doesn't match the `NSMutableDictionary`'s key generic type:

```
NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSNumber *> *foo = [NSMutableDictionary new];
// neither of these calls produces an error. :(
foo[@(42)] = @(42);
[foo setObject:@(42) forKey:@(42)];
```

I see an error when I try to assign an improperly-typed value, so I know generics errors are working somewhat:

```
NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSNumber *> *foo = [NSMutableDictionary new];
foo[@"foo"] = @"bar";
```

Causes the following warning:

```
Foo.m:81:16: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSNumber * _Nullable'
```

Why don't literal assignment or improperly-typed keys cause warnings/errors?

[I filed this as a radar.](http://www.openradar.me/25060179)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this is a limitation/bug of the compiler, caused by the definition of the `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` method:

```
- (void)setObject:(nullable ObjectType)obj forKeyedSubscript:(KeyType <NSCopying>)key;
```

The protocol conforming requirement somehow hides the type requirement for `KeyType`. If `<NSCopying>` is not present, then the compiler makes the `KeyType` check and warns you.

To confirm this, I played with some code, here are the results:

```
@interface MyDictionary<KeyType, ObjectType>: NSObject    
- (void)setObject:(nullable ObjectType)obj forKeyedSubscript:(KeyType <NSCopying>)key;
@end

...

MyDictionary<NSNumber*, NSNumber*>* dict = [[MyDictionary alloc] init];
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
dict[@"98"] = @14; // no warnings
dict[button] = @14; //warning: Sending 'UIButton *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSCopying>'
```

The above code has the same behaviour as `NSMutableDictionary`. However, if I remove the `<NSCopying>` protocol conformance restriction for `KeyType`, then the compiler gives the appropriate warning:

```
@interface MyDictionary<KeyType, ObjectType>: NSObject
- (void)setObject:(nullable ObjectType)obj forKeyedSubscript:(KeyType)key;
@end

...

MyDictionary<NSNumber*, NSNumber*>* dict = [[MyDictionary alloc] init];
dict[@"98"] = @14; // warning: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSNumber *'
```

**Note.** By default you'll get warnings for object types mismatch, if  you want to receive errors, you can either enable the `Treat all warnings as errors` build setting, or just the `Treat Incompatible Pointer Type Warnings as Errors` one.