# Objective-C Generics-Safe Array/Dictionary Literal

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics

Are there warnings I can enable to stop assigning array and dictionary literals to variables with generic types that don't match?

```
// I expect a warning here.
// I'm assigning an NSArray<NSNumber *> to an NSArray<NSString *>
NSArray<NSString *> *strings = @[@1,
                                 @2,
                                 @3,
                                 ];

// I expect a warning here.
// NSDictionary<NSNumber *, NSNumber *>  to an 
// NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> 
NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *stringsByString = @{@1 : @1,
                                                          @2 : @2,
                                                          @3 : @3,
                                                          };
```

I created a new iOS project with Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68), and I got no warnings for the above assignments.

I know I could assign create mutable collections and manually assign each value, and get expected warnings:

```
NSMutableArray<NSString *> *strings = [NSMutableArray new];
[strings addObject:@1];
```

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSNumber *' to parameter of type
>   'NSString * _Nonnull'

```
NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *stringsByString = [NSMutableDictionary new];
stringsByString[@"1"] = @1;
```

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSNumber *' to parameter of type 'NSString * _Nullable'

But I was hoping for something more succinct.

This whole question is more broad than simply calling `-\[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:\` [which doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34916217/9636).

```
stringsByString[@2] = @"2";
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no type inference in Objective-C generics. Hence, array and dictionary literals do not know anything about what context they are used in and must necessarily allow anything as keys and values.

Comment: If you can link to documentation or some official word from someone at Apple (a tweet or email) I'll be happy to mark this correct.